# MFC. Quickly highlight all matches in RichEditCtrl

Tags: c++, stl, mfc

I have a very large text (>50mb).

`FindText`, `SetSel` and `SetSelectionCharFormat` is too slow for me.
I tried to formulate the text and then display but it was even slower.

Can I work with `RichEditCtrl` in memory and then just display?
Or can I speed up the first option or you can solve my problem in another way?

Comment: (1) Do you typically find a LOT of matches? (2) If there is only one match, is it fast? (3) If you only do `FindText` without highlighting - is it fast enough? If the answer to all three questions is `yes` - I would try to disable window update for the duration of this search.

Comment: @VladFeinstein
It works! Thanks! This gave speed increase of 20-50%.
 For the file 56 mb, functions work:
`FindTextA` - 21.6 s;
`FindTextA` + `SetSel` - 23.3 s;
`FindTextA` + `SetSel` + `SetSelectionCharFormat` - 130 s.
Is it possible to speed up the `FindTextA` and `SetSelectionCharFormat` ?

Comment: (1) Do you typically find a LOT of matches? (2) If there is only one match, is it fast? (3) Do you match case and/or whole word?

Comment: (1) Yes, up to several tens of thousands. (2) Yes. (3) No difference is case sensitive or not, just be faster. The word must be a whole, but it may be a part of another word

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My measurements of improvement are different than yours.

Here is my code:

```
void CRichEditAppView::OnEditHighlight()
{
    FINDTEXTEX ft = {};
    ft.chrg = { 0, -1 };
    ft.lpstrText = L"Lorem ipsum";
    DWORD dwFlags(FR_DOWN);
    CHARFORMAT2 cf = {};
    cf.cbSize = sizeof cf;
    cf.dwMask = CFM_BACKCOLOR;
    cf.crBackColor = RGB(255, 255, 0);
    CRichEditCtrl& ctrl = GetRichEditCtrl();
    ctrl.HideSelection(TRUE, FALSE);
    ctrl.SetRedraw(FALSE);
    int count(0);
    while (ctrl.FindTextW(dwFlags, &ft) >= 0)
    {
        ctrl.SetSel(ft.chrgText);
        ctrl.SetSelectionCharFormat(cf);
        ft.chrg.cpMin = ft.chrgText.cpMax + 1;
        count++;
    }
    ctrl.HideSelection(FALSE, FALSE);
    ctrl.SetRedraw(TRUE);
    ctrl.Invalidate();
}
```

I have tested it on a file with 3,000 copies of "Lorem ipsum" text (file size 1,379 KB).

The "naive" implementation (without calls to `HideSelection()` and `SetRedraw()`) took 11 seconds.

Calling `HideSelection()` reduced the time to 9 seconds, adding `SetRedraw()` - to 1.2 seconds. So I expect to see a 10-times improvement.

Just to compare, if I remove a call to `SetSelectionCharFormat()`, I'm only saving 0.4 seconds.